# Calling a sort function on an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am using an insertion sort function to sort a 5000 int ascending array. when i pass the array's address to the function call, i get [Error] name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]. Maybe I should use a vector but I am unfamiliar with them. Maybe I coded something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 5000 //array size
using namespace std;

void insertionSort(int arr[], int length) {
      int i, j, tmp;
      for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                  tmp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                  arr[j - 1] = tmp;
                  j--;
            }
      }
}

int main() {
    int a[SIZE];
    int count = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        a[i] = count;
        count++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }

    insertionSort(&a[i], SIZE);
}
```

Comment: In your `main()` function `i` is not defined when you call `insertionSort(&a[i], SIZE);`. This is because `i` only exists inside of your `for` loops... See @michael-schmitt answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call

```
 insertionSort(a, SIZE)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I thought you could only pass array arguments by reference. I dont just want a fix, could you explain why i didn't have to pass the address instead of just the array? And, thank you again for the advice.

Comment: The array identifier points to the start of the array, so it is essentially the address already.

Answer (score 2):

`// insertionSort(&a[i], SIZE);` Here you haven't declared `i` in funciton `main()`, only in your for loop.
 And the call to `insertionSort` is outside of your loop.

Passing `(&a)[0]` and `a` mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you all for your time.

Comment: '*Passing `(&a)[0]` and `a` mean the same thing.*' – that's wrong. Should be: 'Passing `&(a[0])` and `a` mean the same thing.'